# Member of function Space $C^{1/2}[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider the function space.
$C^{1/2}[0,1]:=\{f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R:\exists K>0$ $such$ $that$ $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq K|x-y|^{1/2}, \forall x,y\in [0,1].\}$
Then both $f(x)=ln(1+x)$ and $g(x)=x^2$ are member of $C^{1/2}[0,1]$.

Please tell me whether these elements belong to the specified  space or not?

Comment: They do. Hint: Both of those functions are $C^1$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Can you please show me in detail?

Comment: I'd need to see some work from you first. What do you know about $C^1$ functions?

Comment: $C^{1}$ is space of continuously differentiable functions. And I can prove $g(x)$ is $C^1$ function.

Comment: $\ln(1+x)=\int_1^x 1/t\textrm{d}t,$ which is continuously differentiable by the fundamental theorem of calculus. But what properties do such functions have?

Comment: Does $C^{1}\subset C^{1/2}$?

Comment: Yes... but you'll probably need to prove that.

Comment: Please help in proving this.

Comment: You need to show some work yourself before you can expect help: What are your ideas? What have you tried? How would you go about showing the above inclusion?

Comment: I think if I can show that $|x-y|≤|x-y|^{1/2}$, then we are done. Which is obvious as $x,y \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Seems reasonable.